# Rails, Tire, Elasticsearch: how to use synonyms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, elasticsearch, tire

I have no idea how to use synonyms/plural with Elasticsearch through Tire gem. Have I a synonyms file to download (an english one in enough)? Something to setup in ES regardless I use Tire or not?

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  attr_accessible :author, :content, :title

  mapping do
    indexes :id, :index => :not_analyzed
    indexes :author, :analyzer => 'keyword'
    indexes :title, :analyzer => 'snowball'
    indexes :content, :analyzer => 'snowball'
  end
end

class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:q].present?
      p = params
      @stories = Story.search(per_page: 30, page: params[:page], load: true) do
        query { string p[:q], default_operator: 'AND' }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I found nothing in documentation...

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What are you specifically aiming for?

Answer (score 2):

i guess you mean the synonym-tokenfilter of elasticsearch: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/synonym-tokenfilter/

```
{
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["synonym"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

afaik in tire, this would go in the `settings` configuration:

```
  settings :analysis => {
             :filter => {
               :synonym  => {
                 "type"          => "synonym",
                 "synonyms_path" => Rails.root.join("config/analysis/synonym.txt").to_s
               }
             },
             :analyzer => {
               :synonym => {
                  "tokenizer"    => "lowercase",
                  "filter"       => ["synonym"],
                  "type"         => "custom" }
             }
           } do
    mapping { indexes :the_field, :type => 'string', :analyzer => "synonym" }
```

Comment: NOTE: you MUST add .to_s to the "synonyms_path" key. Rails.root.join(...) returns a pathname object unrecognized by ElasticSearch and a misleading error will be thrown. Source: stuck on this for over two hours.

Comment: @orangemoney52 adapted the answer accordingly